# how to hide keyboard in UIViewController on return button click->iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, scrollview

Hi I find some questions like that but they talk about textView, I have ViewController, with scrollView where are 6 textfield and one textView I want a function which makes the keyboard disappear on on done/return button click.I implemented functions resign to first responder, which hide my keyboard when i click outside of scrollView, but that is not exactly i want, because i like to make it disappear on button click too.

THanks for any help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set up a class that conforms to the UITextFieldDelegate protocol and make the delegate of your text fields an instance of this class. Implement the method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

As follows:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Hi i found it out so the point with textfields is to add this lines at viewdidload:

```
textFieldOne.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textFieldCislo.delegate = self;
textFieldTwo.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textFieldCislo.delegate = self;
...
```

And this implement method :

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {

    if (theTextField == textFieldOne) {
        [textFieldOne resignFirstResponder];
    }
...
}
```

Comment: add a "return YES;" at bottom to remove warning. Also add " <UITextFieldDelegate>" in the interface to remove more warnings.

Answer (score 3):

U can use this method to hide the keyboard by clicking any where in the view

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After quite a bit of time hunting down something that makes sense, this is what I put together and it worked like a charm.

.h

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  demoKeyboardScrolling
//
//  Created by Chris Cantley on 11/14/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Chris Cantley. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

// Connect your text field to this the below property.
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *theTextField;

@end
```

.m

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  demoKeyboardScrolling
//
//  Created by Chris Cantley on 11/14/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Chris Cantley. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // _theTextField is the name of the parameter designated in the .h file. 
    _theTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    [_theTextField setDelegate:self];

}

// This part is more dynamic as it closes any text field when pressing return.  
// You might want to control every single text field separately but that isn't 
// what this code do.
-(void)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}


@end
```